# Powershell Firebase server timestamp

Tags: json, powershell, firebase, timestamp

In linux and OSX using a curl command I can pass `"firebasetimestamp":{".sv": "timestamp"}` as part of my json data and I get firebase's server timestamp. I'm trying to do the same in Powershell.

```
$firebasetimestamp={".sv: timestamp"}

$body = @{
$UUID = 
    @{
      firebasetimestamp="$firebasetimestamp"
}
}
```

In firebase I get this output. I have played around with using single and double quotes to no avail.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a single string in that first line, not a key-value pair.

I'm not a Powershell expert, but try this: `$firebasetimestamp=@{".sv"= "timestamp"}`.

Comment: I get an error and the powershell script didn't even run. `Unexpected token ':' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken`